# How to make menu fold like paper using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I wish to make a navigational menu that unfolds like paper using CSS only, looking like something like this: http://felixniklas.com/paperfold/ since it's mostly using CSS to create the transition effect.

Unfortunately the effect I get is still not as good, it's like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yaharga/7z2rg8gk/. There are spaces showing and the `li` don't stick together. Ideally I'd like to make the effect show on submenus as well.

I summarized the code to show the transition and transformation css involved:

```js
// Nav Button Toggle
jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.dropdown-toggle.acitve {
  color: #bdc3c7
}

.toggleable {
  -webkit-transition: max-height .75s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .75s ease-in-out, visibility .75s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height .75s ease-in-out, transform .75s ease-in-out, visibility .75s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-perspective: 320px;
  perspective: 320px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.dropdown-toggle.active+.toggleable {
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: 1200px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1)
}

.nav-primary {
  margin: 30px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative
}

#menu-main-toggle {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #c0392b;
}

#menu-main {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute
}

#menu-main,
.toggleable {
  position: relative
}

.dropdown-toggle,
.menu-item {
  background: #e74c3c
}

.menu-item {
  border-top: 1px dashed #c0392b;
  transition: transform .75s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown-toggle.active + #menu-main .menu-item {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.odd {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.even {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

.menu-item.first {
  border-top: none
}

.menu-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 0;
  color: #ecf0f1
}

.menu-link:active {
  color: #fbfcfc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-primary">
  <button id="menu-main-toggle" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu</button>
  <ul id="menu-main" class="nav toggleable hide">
    <li class="odd first menu-item"><a class="menu-link" href="//localhost:3000/index.php/about/">About</a></li>
    <li class="even menu-item"><a class="menu-link" href="/index.php/category/bahrain/">Bahrain</a></li>
    <li class="odd menu-item parent"><a class="menu-link" href="/index.php/category/information-technology/">Information Technology</a>
    </li>
    <li class="even menu-item"><a class="menu-link" href="/index.php/category/snippets/">Snippets</a></li>
    <li class="odd last menu-item"><a class="menu-link" href="//localhost:3000/index.php/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: i don't have time to develop a full answer right now, but here's something i made on codepen some time back that's close to what you want: http://codepen.io/wbarlow/pen/obWqEZ. might be enough to get you started, anyway.

Comment: Paperfold is MIT Licensed and can be used it freely with attribution to the author. The source code is on GitHub so you can see exactly how they are accomplishing the effect (less than 300 lines). You already rely on jQuery in your example; why not utilize Paperfold and try to add in your sub-menus?

Comment: @Sam I'd rather use the stylesheet instead of using jQuery to create inline styles. It uses CSS for the animations anyways. It would be redundant if I included it instead of implementing the effect myself.

Comment: not too sure i get it, but would this be what you look for : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KMMxXX an input and :checked are involved to trigger fold/unfold (rough example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using a negative margin and transitioning that with the same amount of time it takes for the transformation to transition (credit for solution goes to @GCyrillus's codepen). I set the margins as double the size of the menu items as margins collapse so it was perfect. It's the closest I could get to the desired effect, though I would have prefered to get the effect of Felix Niklas's plugin. I think it uses shadows as well, but that cannot be implemented with pure CSS as transitions are linear.

You may correct me on any of which I have said or add to my code.

```js
// Nav Button Toggle
jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.dropdown-toggle.acitve {
  color: #bdc3c7
}

.toggleable {
  -webkit-transition: max-height .75s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .75s ease-in-out, visibility .75s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height .75s ease-in-out, transform .75s ease-in-out, visibility .75s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.toggleable .toggleable {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
}

.dropdown-toggle.active+.toggleable {
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: 1200px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1)
}

#nav-primary {
  margin: 30px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative
}

#menu-main-toggle {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #c0392b;
  height: 50px;
}

#menu-main {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute
}

.dropdown-toggle,
.menu-item {
  background: #e74c3c
}

.menu-item {
  border-top: 1px dashed #c0392b;
  height: 50px;
  transition: transform .75s ease-in-out, margin .75s ease-in-out;
}

#menu-main .menu-item.odd {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(90deg);
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  margin-top: -100px
}
#menu-main .menu-item.even {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  margin-bottom: -100px
}

#nav-primary .dropdown-toggle.active + .toggleable .menu-item {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);
  margin: 0
}

.menu-item.first {
  border-top: none
}

.menu-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #ecf0f1
}

.menu-link:active {
  color: #fbfcfc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav-primary">
  <button id="menu-main-toggle" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu</button>
  <ul id="menu-main" class="nav toggleable hide">
    <li class="odd first menu-item"><a class="menu-link" href="//localhost:3000/index.php/about/">About</a></li>
    <li class="even menu-item"><a class="menu-link" href="/index.php/category/bahrain/">Bahrain</a></li>
    <li class="odd menu-item parent"><a class="menu-link" href="/index.php/category/information-technology/">Information Technology</a>
    </li>
    <li class="even menu-item"><a class="menu-link" href="/index.php/category/snippets/">Snippets</a></li>
    <li class="odd last menu-item"><a class="menu-link" href="//localhost:3000/index.php/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Edit**: For all those interested, I completed the effect using box-shadowing here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38083570/1934402.