# Transition from black to another color through gradient (gradually) from a point with CSS only

Tags: css

`li` states are **closed** and **opened**.

**Closed**: Color is black (there is no light and they are folded onto each other).

**Opened**: Color is red (there is light and they are in full view).

I want the color to fade from the point between the two elements, to show that the shadow starts from the pivot, until they close.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 320px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .75s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: center;
  line-height: 3;
  transition: transform .75s ease-in-out, margin .75s ease-in-out, background .75s ease-in-out;
}
button.active + ul {
  max-height: 100px;
}
button.active + ul > li {
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);
  background: #e74c3c;
  margin: 0;
}
li.odd {
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}
li.even {
  border-top: 1px dashed #bf2718;
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Toggle
</button>
<ul>
  <li class="odd">Lorem</li>
  <li class="even">Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd need a gradient for that and you can't animate those.

Comment: true, but you could fake it, seems a lot of work for a simple effect though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I could see to do this was absolutely positioned 'before' pseudo-element with the gradient applied to it, and the opacity set to 0 when active. I've also added a toggle on the ul itself for the sake of ease.

Easiest to give you the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/efreeman79/8oemm50L/1/

I've added this to the styles:

```
li:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
    /* GRADIENT CSS CODE HERE */
}

.active li:before {
    opacity: 0;
}

li.even:before {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

and this for the sake of ease:

```
$('ul').toggleClass('active');
```

It needs some polish but it does the job. Basically when the ul is active, opacity on the gradient is set to 0, when the active class is removed, the gradient layer's opacity is animated back to 1.

Comment: I decided to go with box-shadowing to get my desired effect. Since you answered the question in the title, though, I ticked yours as the answer, for the sake of those who wish to know the answer to the title. Cheers.

Comment: Ah yea, box shadow... didn't even cross my mind, good choice :) glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to go with box-shadowing instead of gradients. For all those wanting to create an effect similar to what I had in mind, I left the code in my answer.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 320px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .75s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: center;
  line-height: 3;
  background: #e74c3c;
  transition: transform .75s ease-in-out, margin .75s ease-in-out, box-shadow .75s ease-in-out;
}
button.active + ul {
  max-height: 100px;
}
button.active + ul > li {
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
  margin: 0;
}
li.odd {
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(-90deg);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -50px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  transform-origin: top;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}
li.even {
  border-top: 1px dashed #bf2718;
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(90deg);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 50px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Toggle
</button>
<ul>
  <li class="odd">Lorem</li>
  <li class="even">Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```